# Search text in column description

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column which has too much text in it and i want to search so words from that column, How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have to phrase your question better, as it's not too clear as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Full-Text indexing turned on you can use either, [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) or [`FREETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx).  If not, then you can use [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).